# Counting number of points on a raster layer in R

Tags: r, geospatial, kml, r-raster

I've got a map with certain number of points on it. I want to (1) calculate the number of points that fall within the raster layer, and (2) extract these points to a data frame.

This is what I've done:

```
# Packages
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)
library(maptools)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(sp)


# Transform tree ring kml to dataframe
zz<-getKMLcoordinates('treering.kml', ignoreAltitude=TRUE)
l<-as.data.frame(zz)
l<-t(l)

tree <-SpatialPointsDataFrame(l, l,
                                  proj4string = CRS(" +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 
                                  +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0"))


# Get world map
data(wrld_simpl)

# Transform World to raster
r <- raster(wrld_simpl, res = 1)
wrld_r <- rasterize(wrld_simpl, r)

# Import permafrost layer to raster
dist1<-raster("PZI.flt")


# Set CRS
dist1 <- projectRaster(from = dist1, crs = CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
+towgs84=0,0,0"))

# Change colours

micolor <- rev(rainbow(12, alpha = 0.35))
transp <- rainbow(12, alpha = 0)
micolor[1:3] <- transp[1]


# Plot all
plot(wrld_r, col = "lightgrey")
plot(dist1, add=TRUE, legend = F, col = micolor)
plot(tree, add=T, pch = 20, col='black', cex=0.2)
```

I want to calculate and extract black points located on the colorful parts of this map
[image]

Comment: `points_subset <- tree[dist1, ]` , have you checked a simple subset like this. Apparently bracket subsetting works even for spatial objects within R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `raster::projectRaster` does not "set" the projection but, rather reprojects the raster given a transformation and resampling. Given the computational requirements of this it is much faster to reproject the point data using `sp::spTransform`. Once your data is in the same projection space, you can use `raster::extract` to extract the raster values. Values out side the raster or in nodata (NA) areas will be assigned NA values. You can drop these observations using a simple NA index with `which`.

It looks like your data may have a constant value outside of the permafrost. Once you identify what this value is (eg., 0) you can remove these points as well. Here is a worked example. First we add packages and create some example data that is similar to yours.

```
library(sp)
library(raster)

dist1 <- raster(nrow=20, ncol=20)
  dist1[] <- sample(1:10, ncell(dist1), replace=TRUE)
    dist1[200:400] <- 0

trees <- sampleRandom(dist1, 100, sp=TRUE)

plot(dist1)
  plot(trees,pch=20,col="red",add=TRUE)
```

Now, we extract the raster values and look at the dimensions of the point object (please note that I do not have to use the sp=TRUE argument in the `raster::extract` function).

```
trees@data <- data.frame(trees@data, dist1 = extract(dist1, trees))
  dim(trees)
```

Now we create a row index indicating which rows contain zeros, make sure that we have identified rows (using an if statement) and then remove them. Looking at the object dimensions again, we can see how many points were removed from the original point data.

```
( idx <- which(trees$dist1 %in% 0) )
  if(length(idx) > 0) trees <- trees[-idx,]
    dim(trees)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! However, when I try to put in the tree@data I get an error saying "no applicable method for 'extract_' applied to an object of class "c('RasterLayer', 'Raster', 'BasicRaster')"

Comment: In your example code "tree" is an sp SpatialPointsDataFrame object and "dist1" is a raster object. If this is the case, the raster extract should work with `extract(dist1, tree)`. The tree@data call is referencing the data slot holding the data.frame in the sp object. Thus, this is appending the data.frame in a single step. The error you are receiving is indicating that tree is in fact a raster object and not sp points.

Comment: Yeah, that would make sense. But I just double checked and 'dist1' is of a class Raster Layer, and 'tree' is of a class SpatialPointsDataFrame. Not sure what could be going on here?

Comment: It just occurred to me, do you actually have the raster package loaded? You can use `raster::extract` to call the function from the raster package environment. You should also have the sp package loaded. If you are reprojecting the points, you should also load rgdal to support `spTransform`. It is an odd and undocumented requirement for the function in sp. To assign a projection, rather than reproject, you would use: `proj4string(dist1) <- "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0"`

Comment: Thanks for your ongoing help, I appreciate it a lot. I figured it out that if I use `data.frame(tree@data, extract(dist1, tree, sp=TRUE))` it works. However, it extracts all of the tree data (all blue points on the map) instead of just the ones located on dist1 (colorful areas). Not sure why?